# What's the best way to store decimal degrees in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have latitude and longitude columns in my table.

I'm currently storing latitude with `float(16,14)` and longitude with `float(17,14)`. Is that the best way to store them? The values I'm inserting are from JS `navigator.geolocation`, and they don't tend to have more than 14 digits after the decimal place.

Should I be using `decimal` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html) type stores *exact* numeric data values (if you use MySQL5.0.3 or above), the [`FLOAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/floating-point-types.html) type represents *approximate* numeric data values.

Since as far as I know latitude and longitude values are usually exact numeric data values for most use cases, I'd go for a [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html).

Comment: Okay, what happens if I insert a value that's longer than 16 or 17, respectively, digits though? Will it just cut the extra digits from the end?

Comment: Digital measurements derived from observation of continuous real-world phenomena are NEVER exact numeric values.  Latitude and longitude are continuous real-world phenomena.

Comment: Very true, edited my first reply slightly. But if I may say so from a coding perspective this still ain't worth using a `FLOAT` here for most use cases. @user1274763 The maximum number of digits for `DECIMAL` is 65, so this should give you enough numeric space to work with.

Comment: @Bjoern Thanks, just wanted to check it would be precise enough.

Answer (score 3):

You should use decimal! Read on this: [Problems with Floating-Point Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html)